# What happened between Korben and Leeloo?

Tags: the-fifth-element

At the very end of *The Fifth Element*, Korben and Leeloo are stripped and placed in some kind of healing device. Is this strictly for medical purposes, or are we to believe that they engaged in sexual intercourse?

Comment: The device is the same one used to regenerate Leeloo earlier in the film. The final shot of the film is of them making out in the same device.

Comment: @phantom42 thanks, sounds like the answer is "yes" then

Comment: It's fairly unambiguiys what they are doing in there if you watch carefully.

Comment: Supposedly, we have a Word of God answer, but I can't find a real reference - just a mention on TVTropes...

Comment: Well, I found the source of that Word of God answer:  imdb, which seems to have then been copied all over the internet.  But the actual interview it supposedly came from, I can't find any mention of, let alone a transcript.

Comment: You see @Sandy when a man and a "Supreme Being" save the entire universe from imminent destruction they can have certain...urges...

Comment: I've always thought it was blatantly obvious that they were having sex.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, if you consider that *"kissing and probably engaged in hoppi hoppa"* is sexual intercourse.

Here a quote from [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Fifth-Element,-The.html):

> ```
> 283   INT.  LABORATORY
>
> We are in the Nucleological Laboratory that gave birth to Leeloo in the
> beginning of our story. The President enters the lab followed by a group
> of officials in ceremonial dress.
>
>                     MUNRO
>             Mr. President, let me introduce you to
>             Professor Mactilburgh, who runs the center.
>
>                     MACTILBURGH
>             It's an honor to receive you. Mr. President.
>
>                     PRESIDENT
>                 (beaming)
>             Yes.. Well? Where are our two heroes?
>
>                     MACTILBURGH
>             They were so tired from their ordeal that
>             we put them in the reactor this morning..
>
>                     PRESIDENT
>             I have 19 more meetings after this one
>             Professor..
>
>                     PROFESSOR
>             Of course.. Let me see if they're revived.
>
>                     AIDE
>             We go live in one minute, Mr. President.
>
> Mactilburgh goes to the reactor and opens a small slot which allows him to see what is 
> going on under the blue shield.
>
> Leeloo and Korben are naked, arms wrapped around each other, kissing 
> and probably engaged in hoppi hoppa.
> Mactilburgh looks troubled.
>
>                     MACTILBURGH
>           I.. uh.. they need five more minutes,
>           Mr. President.
> ```

---

**Update :**

In an other part of the script, they confirm exactly what is *hoppi hoppa* :

> ```
>                       KORBEN
>             You learned 900 languages in five
>             minutes?!
>                       LEELOO
>                 (pleased)
>             Yes! Now it's your turn! I learned your
>             language, you have to learn mine!
>
>                       KORBEN
>             I know how to say "Hello". Teach me how
>             to say "Good-bye", that's all I need.
>
>                       LEELOO
>             Apipoussan!
>
>                       KORBEN
>             Apipoussan?
>
>                       LEELOO
>             Good! Do you know how we say "make love"?
>
>                       KORBEN
>                 (fumbling)
>             Uh...
>
>                       LEELOO
>             ...Hoppi-hoppa.
> ```